# How to generate vertx code with openapitools code generator maven plugging

Tags: java, maven, vert.x, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate vertx code from openAPITools maven plugging. So when the project get build source code need to generate according to provided openapi.ymal file. See the pom file as below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-openapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <openapi-generator-version>5.2.0</openapi-generator-version>
        <vertx.version>4.1.2</vertx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${openapi-generator-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator</artifactId>
            <version>${openapi-generator-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-openapi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-api-contract</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-openapi</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-sql-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-mysql-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-sql-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-jdbc-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${openapi-generator-version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <environmentVariables>
                                <supportingFiles>ApiClient.java</supportingFiles>
                            </environmentVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Ran the **mvn clean compile** . but code not generating. what is missing in the pom? or any miss configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I was able generate the code with following execution in maven openapi generator plugin

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- specify the swagger yaml -->
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>

                        <!-- target to generate vertx client code -->
                        <generatorName>java-vertx-web</generatorName>

                        <output>${project.basedir}</output>
                        <apiPackage>com.test.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.test.model</modelPackage>
                        <invokerPackage>com.test.client</invokerPackage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
```